# Cannot load File in Scheme, (using Simply Scheme Book and PLT Scheme)

Tags: scheme, racket

I am using PLT Scheme (DrScheme). I want to load a file that I got from [here](ftp://anarres.cs.berkeley.edu/pub/scheme/simply.scm). To load the file, I go into PLT Scheme and in the interactions window (or the bottom window), I type (load "simply.scm") and then press enter. It gives me this error:

simply.scm:20:12: set!: cannot mutate module-required identifier in: number->string

I have no clue how to fix that, please assist...

Extra Info: I am learning out of the book *Simply Scheme Introducing Computer Science* by Brian Harvey and Matthew Wright

Also, the link takes a little long to load, but it does work, i think they have the files on a really old server, so that may be why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open DrScheme (or DrRacket as the newer version of the software is now called); from the Language menu select "Choose Language..." and make sure "Use the language declared in the source" is checked.

Then at the top of your file, put the following two header lines followed by whatever code you want from the book (I've chosen an example from the first chapter):

```
#lang racket
(require (planet dyoo/simply-scheme))

(define (pigl wd)
  (if (member? (first wd) 'aeiou)
      (word wd 'ay)
      (pigl (word (butfirst wd) (first wd)))))
```

Then click run. This should allow you to also type expressions in the Interactions pane to evaluate them.

Alternatively, you can replace the two lines above with one:

```
#lang planet dyoo/simply-scheme
```

But then the Simply Scheme language is not enabled in the Interactions pane.

You can find the documentation for this DrScheme/Racket `simply-scheme` library by clicking on the 'docs' link at [the URL provided by Chris](http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=simply-scheme.plt&owner=dyoo).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not getting that error now. Everything is working fine :)

Answer (score 7):

You should use the [Racket Simply Scheme module](http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=simply-scheme.plt&owner=dyoo). The file you have linked to is not compatible with Racket.

More specifically, in Racket, you're not allowed to use `set!` to overwrite existing function bindings, which is what that file does. (Technically, it can potentially break other Scheme implementations also, so this isn't a "Racket quirk" or anything.)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but can you tell me how I could get that file to work so that it wont break other scheme implementations? And, is there a better scheme interpreter than plt or racket for windows that you would recommend?

Comment: The simply.scm library should work other many other scheme implementations.  Racket deviates from standard Scheme with regards to set-car! and set-cdr!, which the Simply Scheme bindings depended on.  The package on PLaneT makes some light edits to adapt it to Racket, and is derived from the original scheme.scm sources.  If you see any deviations between it and the original in terms of behavior, those are bugs that I should fix!  :)

By the way, I see a huge upsurge of downloads of my package recently.  Has a class started up this week?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not aware of any classes that have started up this week :)